# Пользователь вводит строку из слов, разделённых пробелами. Сколько слов этом предложении имеют длину менее 4?

Tags: python

Дали вот такое задание в процессе знакомства с Python.

Моя логика такова: нужно найти индексы пробелов в строке и посчитать расстояния между ними. Билась над этим не один день и ни к чему не пришла. Возможно ли такое? Как посчитать эти расстояния?

Буду признательна за помощь, если сможете усовершенствовать и закончить **мой** код и укажете на ошибки.

Код, который родился, ниже.

```
s=input('Введите текст: ')
count=0
answer=0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i]==' ':
        print('Индекс пробела: ', i)
        if i<4:
            answer+=1
print('Число слов длиной менее 4-х символов: ', answer)
```

Comment: Для начала воспользуйтесь методом `split()`, чтобы разделить строку на отдельные слова по пробелам. А дальше считайте длины этих слов.

Comment: @CrazyElf большое спасибо! Попробовала не смотреть на предложенное решение и просто изучить `split()`. Все получилось!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = input('Введите текст: ')
values = text.split(' ') #Разделяем строку по пробелам
answer_values = [value for value in values if len(value) < 4] #Оставляем слова с кол-вом букв < 4
answer = len(answer_values) #Считаем количество оставшихся слов
print(answer)
```

Comment: 1) Не делайте за других простые задания, они так ничему не научатся 2) вам ведь не нужен список подходящих слов, так считайте сразу их количество (через `sum`)

Comment: 1) Это ответ ради обучения, что бы человек, начавший изучение Python увидел, какие методы можно использовать, как можно работать с циклом и условием в одну строку и т.д.
2) Я согласен с вами, что мой код можно еще сократить, но к сожалению, это может запутать автора, поэтому написал так подробно